How to return multiple properties while using a split extension in jsonpath-ng?
I'm working with a dictionary in Python, such as:
event = {'name': 'team1 - team2', 'competitionId': 19790, 'sportId': 3}

I am trying to extract the name value and split it using the split extension. The extraction works as expected when returning the name value separately, like this:
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse

jsonpath_expression = parse("$.name.`split(-, 0, -1)`")
# This returns: 'team1 '

However, when I try to return multiple properties, including the split name value alongside other properties, I encounter an error:
jsonpath_expression = parse("$.[sportId, dateTime, name.`split(-, 0, -1)`]")
# Error: raise JsonPathParserError('Parse error at %s:%s near token %s (%s)'

How can I return multiple properties (including the split name value) at once, while avoiding this error?

from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse

def split_name(node):
    name = node.value['name']
    split_name = name.split(' - ', 1)[0]
    return {
        'sportId': node.value['sportId'],
        'dateTime': node.value.get('dateTime'),
        'splitName': split_name
    }

jsonpath_expression = parse("$.[sportId, dateTime, name]")
event_data = [{'name': 'team1 - team2', 'competitionId': 19790, 'sportId': 3}]
result = [split_name(match) for match in jsonpath_expression.find(event_data)]

print(result)

one-line alternative:
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse

jsonpath_expression = parse("$.[sportId, dateTime, name]")
event_data = [{'name': 'team1 - team2', 'competitionId': 19790, 'sportId': 3}]
result = [{
    'sportId': match.value['sportId'],
    'dateTime': match.value.get('dateTime'),
    'splitName': match.value['name'].split(' - ', 1)[0]
} for match in jsonpath_expression.find(event_data)]

print(result)

another way
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse

jsonpath_expression = parse("$.[sportId, dateTime, name, name.split(' - ', 1)[0] as splitName]")
event_data = [{'name': 'team1 - team2', 'competitionId': 19790, 'sportId': 3}]
result = [match.value for match in jsonpath_expression.find(event_data)]

print(result)


This works, however I am looking for a single jsonpath_expression, without any additional code.

In my opinion - it is more readable code, but i will update answer with one-line expression

oh i missed - you mean not one-line code but one-line  expression in parse

Yes, I meant a one-line expression. Unfortunately, the second solution fails since you are using a Python split method inside a parser.

i find split inside docs - https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-ng/ extension section
Extensions
split
$.field.split(+, 2, -1)
$.field.split(sep, segement, maxsplit)

Sure, but you are missing the back quotes around name.split(' - ', 1) and the index [0] is not valid too. When this is fixed we are back to my original solution which does not work.
